# how to get each object from a many-to-many relationship

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, jdo

Person is an object has name and favoriteFoods,
Food is an object has name and foodFans.

the relationship between Person and Food is many to many
A person can have lots of favoriteFoods,
and the food can have lots of foodFans

i wrote a simple java to get the each favoriteFoods from one person
i want to know what i have done is correct?
Is there a better solution?

THANKS

```
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    //select from ...
    Query query = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
    //where ...
    query.setFilter("name == nameParam");
    //order by ...
    query.setOrdering("id desc");
    //declare a parameter to use later
    query.declareParameters("String nameParam");
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        //execute query
        List<Person> results = (List<Person>) query.execute(person_name);
        //if found
        if (results.iterator().hasNext()) {
            for (Person p : results) {
                out.println("<p>" + p.getKey() + "</p>");
                out.println("<p>" + p.getName() + "</p>");
                Set<Key> foods = p.getFavoriteFoods();
                Iterator<Key> i = foods.iterator();
                while(i.hasNext()) {
                    Food f = pm.getObjectById(Food.class, i.next());
                    out.println("<p>" + f.getName()+ "</p>");
                    i.remove();
                }
            }
        } else {
            out.println("<p>Not Found.</p>");
        }
    } finally {
        query.closeAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you're using JDO. the app engine JDO docs use this exact example - people and favorite foods - and they [describe one recommended way to implement it: unowned many-to-many relationship](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/relationships.html#Unowned_Relationships).

specifically, you'd first determine which side will generally have fewer related entities. in this case, the average Food will probably have more fans (millions) than the average Person will have favorite foods (tens to hundreds).

put a key list property in Person, e.g. `Set<Key> favoriteFoods`, for their favorite foods. to get a person's favorite foods, you'd just load the Person entity (which costs one datastore get) and look at the `favoriteFood` set. to get a food's fans, you'd query for the Person entities whose `favoriteFood` property contains (`=` in GQL) that food.